# How do BI tools allow arbitrary querying against data when they don't know what it looks like yet?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

In a star schema, you have to pre-define columns and as new data points arise, you have to update your schema.

My question is:

How do BI tools like Tableau and Looker allow you to arbitrarily query against dimensions and facts when they don't know what your data will look, while remaining performant?

I'm aware of EAV pattern but don't you lose the benefits of a schema like star? Are these companies storing as EAV and running post-processing for pivot tables and not following something like star?

Comment: [Please do not cross post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) also posted here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/171735/1822

Comment: You would only have to update your schema if your new data points are of a different schema. Seems obvious but thought I'd clarify. When you get to the stage of something like Tableau, your schema is very concretely defined. They allow you to make arbitrary queries, because they don't presuppose your *query*, and the star schema allows for very general querying, but the schema is determined as per the structure of the data you do have. It is up to you in Tableau to define your schemas for users to then query. Tableau does not generate a schema.